Rule for when a commit tag exists AND is on the default branch?
I'm creating a Gitlab pipeline. I want to run a release only when the commit is on the default branch and the commit has a tag attached to it. Here's my code:
release_job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  release:
    tag_name: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    name: "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    description: "Release created using the release-cli."
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_TAG

The problem is this isn't running.
It works with just the tag part:
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG

But then this runs a release when a tag is created on any branch.
It also works with just the branch part:
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

But then this will run a release every time a commit is made to the default branch, not only when a tag exists.
I've also tried with $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH instead of $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME. Same result.
So how can I get it to run only if both of these conditions are true?

I believe a pipeline that runs after tag creation will have the tag name as CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME since tags are basically branches. Also CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is not available for tag pipelines. You can find this info in the documentation. Depending on your tag structure: Would it work for you to release only if the tag has the form of e.g. release_v1.2.3 and ignore all other tags?

Yeah thats basically what I ended up with. I decided to use $CI_COMMIT_TITLE to only run when the commit title is /release xyz. So $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /\/release\b/

Lets wait, maybe someone else has a better solution :)
